# PHP copy/fopen etc. times out

Tags: php, timeout, fopen

I am copying a file from a remote server using copy (and also tried various versions with fopen, file_get_contents etc.) but after ~2 minutes the script times out. No errors, no exceptions. In the error log file it says: (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Any clue?

Here is my php.ini config for resource limits:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 0     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 104M     ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

and this might be related, too:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
default_socket_timeout = 60
```

I added a new php.ini in the folder

```
[PHP]

max_input_time = 3600

default_socket_timeout = 3600

max_execution_time = 3600

upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

But that didn't help.

EDIT:
It seems to be a problem with the filesize. As soon as it reaches 2MB the server fails. I have to contact my hoster.

Comment: is the file actually reachable from the web?

Comment: Thanks for checking out SO.  Generally we don't put thanks or signature lines onto questions or answers.  Can check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Yes, it is. It works fine dowloading the file directly via browser.

Comment: is the file available directly, or do you need to login to a service to download it?

Comment: yes, it is a normal file. no cookie, session, post... data is needed

Comment: Hi.  max_execution_time excludes time spent copying files, I think.  You may not be able to change that depending on whether you're on shared hosting or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php.ini file is most likely configured to timeout after 120 seconds.  I'm not sure what kind of server you have, but on mine the primary php.ini file is located in:
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

If you can't find it, run phpinfo() in a script and you will find the directory to your main php.ini

Under the RESOURCE LIMITS heading, change the timeout in seconds and restart your server

Comment: After looking at stackuser10210's answer, I realized that you need to change two settings in php.ini.  Both the max_input_time and max_execution_time

Comment: now i tried wget via System/shell. but it also fails wenn it reaches 2000kb. Do you knie what i have to change to bypass the 2000 kb limit?

Answer (score 2):

It could be max_input_time (the default would be 60 secs?).  You might want to try increasing it in php.ini.  If you're on shared hosting, you can try placing a php.ini file in the directory.

max_input_time = 3600

would give you one hour.

Comment: I created a php.ini and validated it through php_ini_loaded_file and ini_get_all. The contents of my new php.ini is `[PHP] max_input_time = 3600

default_socket_timeout = 3600

max_execution_time = 3600

upload_max_filesize = 10M` But that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the php.ini for:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
default_socket_timeout = 60
```