# Fake an exception on Laravel Storage Disk

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit

Hello I'm trying unsuccessfully to emulate an exception or a problem with the purpose of testing the code that handles that error, testing the happy case, successful upload it's easy but the exception cases I couldn't find information about them

This is a snippet of the code in question, just uploading a file to a storage disk

```php
private function code_that_runs_on_the_app(string $file, string $filename)
{
    $disk = Storage::disk('a_disk_used_for_this');

    if ($disk->putFileAs('/', $file, $filename)) {
        unlink($file);
    } else {
        // Handle the error case, like some write permission error 
    }
}
```

This is the test that "fails" because it actually upload the file, I need to fake an error on the putFileAs could be an exception or a null response

```php
public function it_tests_some_part_of_my_code()
{
    $disk = Storage::fake('a_disk_used_for_this');

    // Here comes some code that triggers the code needed

    // Because it supposedly failed this should be empty
    $this->assertEmpty($disk->allFiles());
}
```

Reading about that on the documentation found that I could use something like

```php
Storage::shouldReceive('putFileAs')->once()->andThrow(new \Exception('Testing'));
$disk = Storage::fake('a_disk_used_for_this');
...
```

But it fails even on that step.

Do you know a way to fake like a timeout error, a connection error, permissions error, etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: Yeah the "error" is that I'm having trouble trying to create a mocked error, when I do tests I like to assert the happy path, and the exceptions, and I need to replicate in a test an error uploading a file to a Storage Disk

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is not working for you, but I think this will help you:

```php
public function it_tests_some_part_of_my_code()
{
    Storage::shouldReceive('putFileAs')
        ->once()
        ->andThrow(new Exception($errorMessage = 'Testing'));

    Storage::shouldReceive('disk')
        ->once()
        ->andReturnNull();

    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage($errorMessage);


    // Call the class/method that is going to trigger this exception
}
```

Comment: It does not work, if you try to run that code, when the application tries to get the disk it fails, you could try it even just after the partial mock sentence, call Storage::disk('a_disk_used_for_this') and it would throw an ErrorException with the message "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Comment: Well, I would have to see the Laravel's source code to understand better what is going on and give a solution. You could also "fake" the `disk` call, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

to test a timeout error, you can get inspired by [PHP copy/fopen etc. times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046139/php-copy-fopen-etc-times-out). Personally, haven't tried, but you can try out setting the time limit to very low value.

To test a connection error, trying to copy to some random-not-existing server might work. Simply set the `where to copy` parameter to `https://a/`

To test permission, you can create a directory within a test using `mkdir()` and then set its permissions using `chmod` or `chown`.

To be clear, I have not tried any of these, but they should work to throw the errors/exceptions.

Comment: Those kind of could work, but I already think about them and I don't like them primarily because in the first and second case, the test needs to get a timeout, so it implies waiting for it, at the best scenario change the PHP ini configurations to reduce the waiting time, but still wait. And it's not a "Laravelish" approach

Comment: To not wait, you might set the timeout_limit directly within the test, set to lets say 1 second. For the second test, you do not need to wait. The test should directly get an error message from the server, that it is not allowed to upload anything in there (you might use an ftp as well). And even better, if the server name does not exists, the program is not able to ping it so you get the error message within a short time too.

Comment: This is a good solution, not for Laravel. Laravel uses Facades (`Storage`), so you can mock the facade as the author did, it simply is not correctly working, but you should about using any PHP native function to "fake" something when using Laravel.

Comment: Yeah mainly I don't like this kind of solution because it's like brute force the result, It needs to change PHP configurations, I'm looking for a mocked response instead